# Replace multiple characters in string on keyup

Tags: jquery, replace

I want to help my users to add a correct string do be used as a meta_key in the database by not allowing illegal characters and replacing bad characters with good ones. I have this and its working great.

```
$('.custom_field_name').keyup(function () { 
    var v = this.value.replace(/\W/,'');
    if (v!=this.value) this.value = v;
});
```

But i also want to replace space '   ' with a underline '_', and I have been trying codes like this, not getting anywhere.

```
$('.custom_field_name').keyup(function () { 
    var v = this.value.replace(/\W/,'') && (' ','_');
    if (v!=this.value) this.value = v;
});
```

or

```
$('.custom_field_name').keyup(function () { 
    var v = this.value.replace(/\W/,'');
    var v = this.value.replace(' ','_');
    if (v!=this.value) this.value = v;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't declare `v` variable twice, use that :

```
$('.custom_field_name').keyup(function () { 
    var v = this.value.replace(/\W/,'');
    v = v.replace(' ','_');
    this.value = v;
});
```

Comment: That did not work, but you pointed me in the right direction! I had to make the space to _ first and the rest after.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work with this code! Also added toLowerCase().
Problem was not to declare v twice (@GGO) and change the order.

```
jQuery('.custom_field_name').keyup(function () { 
           var v = this.value.replace(' ','_');
           var vee = v.toLowerCase().replace(/\W/,'');
           if (vee!=this.value) this.value = vee;
});
```